# Jquery If integer equals on click event

Tags: jquery, variables, if-statement, onclick, toggle

Hello guys I am trying to achieve something with jquery but I cant get it to work.
I want the button `.btn-toggler` to fire event if the value of my variable `da` equals -150. The value of `da` is the `margin-left` value of another element's class. If I work it out on developer tools console log, my `parseInt` function returns -150 but `da` is `undefined`!

Edit: I changed `$da` into `da` as suggested but it still doesn't work!

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var da = 0;
    $('.btn-toggler').click(function() {
        da = parseInt($(".sidemenu").css('marginLeft'));
        if (da == -150) {
            $('.sidemenu').addClass('active-nav');
            $('.body').addClass('bodyactivenav');
        }
        else {
            $('.sidemenu').removeClass('active-nav');
            $('.body').removeClass('bodyactivenav');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: why you check the `marginLeft`. It looks like you can check also the class `active-nav` with `hasClass()`

Comment: Actually, `active-nav` seems useless to me in this whole example. Your toggle should just `$('body').toggleClass('bodyactivenav')` and you could change your CSS and style the now `.active-class whatever` into `.bodyactivenav whatever`... This would eliminate the need for any check.

Comment: Oh I never thought to do it like that, thanks a lot!